# Auditing Registry events through AD

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-event-log, windows-registry, audit

I want to audit registry related events (modify key delete key etc) , so i enabled it via group policy and setup a "Global Object Access Auditing" for auditing on "Authenticated Users". Unfortunately the event count it too high and almost 95% of them are from "NT SYSTEM". Below are my questions;

-> Why is "NT SYSTEM" part of "Authenticated Users"?
-> What should i select in the "Global Object Access Auditing", which limits auditing to all interactive and non interactive users except SYSTEM.?

Edit: If i were to use, "Domain Users" i need to create seperate entry for each domain in the forest and out fo forest; i am wishing, it were to be last resort move.

Comment: What is a GACL?

Comment: @RyanRies A GACL of geese, of course.

Comment: My bad , Replaced Gacl with "Global Object Access Auditing".

Answer (score 0):

Authenticated users is not a group that contains members. It's a condition.

Set it to Domain Users.

Comment: Should i be creating seperate entry for all the domains in the forest? and same with the out of forest domains?

Comment: This is a vital bit of information that wasn't in our question prior to your edit. You could get around this by creating a universal security group in your forest root domain and making Domain Users from each child domain a member.